# .NET Core 2.2 Azure Function v2 Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I am having an issue registering a singleton using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. I have created a `Startup` class (which is definitely working) and created an `ITestService` with implementation.

The singleton is injected into the function's constructor. Initially I had no issues with this implementation, however, a couple days later the function fails because it can't resolve `ITestService`. I have no clue why.

here is the `Startup` class

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Test.Functions
{
    using System;

    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITestService>(new TestService("test string"));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the function

```
public class TestFunction
{
    private readonly ITestService testService

    public TestFunction(ITestService testService)
    {
        this.testService = testService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testService));
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(TestFunction))]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("test", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]Message message, ILogger log)
    {
        ////use test service here
    }
}
```

When I debug startup and look at `Services` I see that the implementation type is `null` for `ITestService`, which I assume is why it won't resolve. Like I mentioned this totally worked for a couple days. The version of functions etc have not changed. Any ideas how to get this working again would be greatly appreciated.

**update**

I tried to simplify this even further and created another dummy interface with an implementation that has a parameter-less constructor. I added it using:
`builder.AddSingleton<ITestService2, TestService2>()`

It obviously assigned the type to the implementation type, but when it came time to inject it into the constructor it failed with the same can't activate exception.

Comment: Did you try it with services.BuildServiceProvider();

Comment: @Azzy I did give that a try but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a regression in the latest version of the function host that has broken Dependency Injection.

In order to work around this in an Azure environment, you can lock down the specific version of the functions host by setting the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` application setting to `2.0.12342.0`.

If you're running the function host locally using the [`azure-functions-core-tools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools) NPM package, be sure to use `2.4.419` as the latest version (2.4.498) results in the same issue. You can install that explicitly with the following:

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@2.4.419
```

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4187#issuecomment-476053609) for more background.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ITestService, TestService>();
}
```

Comment: About the downvoter. The suggestion is correct. Check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_. It should be a goot practice to explain why is the downvote.

Comment: @AzzyElvul Looks like the call to `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITestService>(new TestService("test string"));` is also correct and the suggestion might just not answer the initial question...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you notice TestService takes a string as the parameter so your solution will not work for that

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work as at startup the Dependency `TestService` requires a string value to satisfy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Have a go with this

```
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITestService>(s => new TestService("test string"));
```

This uses the `IServiceProvider` in order to provide the `string` parameter to the constructor.

EDIT :

Try Changing your code to the below and installing [Willezone.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Willezone.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DependencyInjection)

This adds the extension method `AddDependencyInjection` and allows you to do the traditional `ConfigureServices` method call in a net core app startup.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;

 [assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
   namespace Test.Functions
{
using System;

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddDependencyInjection(ConfigureServices)
            .Build();

    }
  private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddSingleton<ITestService>(s => new TestService("test string"));
  }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but still the same result. It actually made a lot of sense because that is what I do when I use Autofac.

Comment: @AnotherDev very strange. We use this approach across the board and works fine.

Comment: That extension method actually hangs off the builder object so builder.AddDependencyInjection(ConfigureService). I tried that and still no dice